# _.template not working - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Trying to output some value from View via template by using Backbone.js, but the list item is not showing on webpage, please have a look and advise what is missing. Thank you

```
<script type="text/template" id="myid">
    <li>  <%= value %> </li>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:'ul',
        initialize:function(){
            this.template = _.template($('#myid').html());
        },
        render:function(){
        this.$el.append(this.template({value:"Joe Blogg"}));
        return this;    
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        myListView = new ListView();
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: The only reason why this isn't working is you're not calling the `render()`. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this.

```
(function($){
    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:'ul',
        $el: $(this.tagName),
        initialize:function(){
            this.template = _.template($('#myid').html());
        },
        render:function(){
            this.$el.append(this.template({value:"Joe Blogg"}));
            $('body').append(this.$el);
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var myListView = new ListView(); // call initialize()
        myListView.render(); // call render()
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I use jQuery.js and Underscore.js and Backbone.js.

And Always Use "var".

Comment: Thanks Gecko :) $el: $(this.tagName)  is helpful to me

Comment: You don't need to do `$el: $(this.tagName);`, that's just doing more work than necessary. `tagName` automatically becomes the `el` if `tagName` is declared. Calling the `this.render();` fixes the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   this.$el.empty();
   this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
```

In your **DOM ready** event call the `.render()` method

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     myListView = new ListView();
     myListView.render(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `render` and then actually add your view's `el` to the page somewhere.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var myListView = new ListView();
   $("body").append(myListView.render().el); 
 });
```